# Solving differential equations with trigonometric functions using laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Can this DE be solved using Laplace transform?

$$
L\;\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} + A\cos(\theta) +g\sin(\theta) = 0
$$

where g , A , L are constants

Comment: If you want to use the Laplace transform method, then you should know about the initial conditions of the ordinary differential equation for your problem.

Comment: @Александр it's the Laplace transform of $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ that is problematic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Laplace transform works for linear equations.

You can handle your equation as
$$\dot\theta\ddot\theta+\dot\theta(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta)=0$$
and by integration
$$\dot\theta^2=2a\sin\theta-2b\cos\theta+c.$$

This separable equation leads you to an elliptic integral, then to a Jacobi function, something not too exotic. (Note that by adding a suitable constant to $\theta$, you can let one of the sine or cosine term vanish.)